# Are this subdomain CNAME and A record settings correct?

Tags: subdomain

I want to add a simple subdomain named

"tr.acme.com"

to my website. I tried following DNS record settings:

[image: DNS Settings]

No matter what i try, i can't get this subdomain working.

Would someone please correct me how to set this subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields for the CNAME should be:

- Type: CNAME
- Name: tr
- Data: www.latte42.com

Basically, the CNAME needs to point to an A record.

Comment: i also want that it points to the proper subfolder, does this type of entry make this?

Comment: That would be a separate issue from the DNS entry and would be reliant about the server configuration. Most control panels should allow you to point visitors to tr.latte42.com to a different subfolder on your server, but there is no DNS entry that will do that for you.

Comment: So after i add this entry, and configure (add a subdomain in cPanel) this should work right?

Comment: Yes, and cpanel may be able to do everything for you (Apache configuration, DNS settings, and creating the subfolder). I'd first try deleting this subdomain and then trying the directions here: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/SubDomains